# How to fetch value from XML in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a XML like below. In this i want to fetch 'Name' value. i.e AAA in SQL Server.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:out="http://www.google.com">
  <soapenv:Body>
  <MER xmlns="http://www.google.com/services">
  <ns1:RequestHeader xmlns:ns1="http://www.google.com//services">
    <ns1:Info>
      <ns1:Name>AAA</ns1:Name>
      <ns1:TransactionId>Mdow0-NHPHuNu7eiEUxb</ns1:TransactionId>
      <ns1:SubmitDateTime>2015-09-12T15:48:44.000Z</ns1:SubmitDateTime>
      <ns1:SessionId>Mdow0-NHPHuNu7eiEUxb</ns1:SessionId>
      <ns1:Timeout>60</ns1:Timeout>
      <ns1:MaxRows>100</ns1:MaxRows>
      <ns1:TransactionLog>
        <ns1:Info1>1234567</ns1:Info1>
        <ns1:Info2>ABC123</ns1:Info2>
      </ns1:TransactionLog>
    </ns1:Info>
    <ns1:CorrelatedData>
      <ns1:UserID>ABC123</ns1:UserID>
      <ns1:UserRole>My Members</ns1:UserRole>
      <ns1:TransactionName>Login</ns1:TransactionName>
      <ns1:ClientSubmitDateTime>2010-09-12 11:48:44 PM</ns1:ClientSubmitDateTime>
    </ns1:CorrelatedData>
  </ns1:RequestHeader>
  <SearchCriteria>
    <MemberID>123456</MemberID>
  </SearchCriteria>
</MER>
```

Comment: … and what keeps you from fetching the 'Name' value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/3190/0)**

```
DECLARE @x XML = 
 N'<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:out="http://www.google.com">
  <soapenv:Body>
  <MER xmlns="http://www.google.com/services">
  <ns1:RequestHeader xmlns:ns1="http://www.google.com//services">
    <ns1:Info>
      <ns1:Name>AAA</ns1:Name>
      <ns1:TransactionId>Mdow0-NHPHuNu7eiEUxb</ns1:TransactionId>
      <ns1:SubmitDateTime>2015-09-12T15:48:44.000Z</ns1:SubmitDateTime>
      <ns1:SessionId>Mdow0-NHPHuNu7eiEUxb</ns1:SessionId>
      <ns1:Timeout>60</ns1:Timeout>
      <ns1:MaxRows>100</ns1:MaxRows>
      <ns1:TransactionLog>
        <ns1:Info1>1234567</ns1:Info1>
        <ns1:Info2>ABC123</ns1:Info2>
      </ns1:TransactionLog>
    </ns1:Info>
    <ns1:CorrelatedData>
      <ns1:UserID>ABC123</ns1:UserID>
      <ns1:UserRole>My Members</ns1:UserRole>
      <ns1:TransactionName>Login</ns1:TransactionName>
      <ns1:ClientSubmitDateTime>2010-09-12 11:48:44 PM</ns1:ClientSubmitDateTime>
    </ns1:CorrelatedData>
  </ns1:RequestHeader>
  <SearchCriteria>
    <MemberID>123456</MemberID>
  </SearchCriteria>
</MER>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>';


WITH XMLNAMESPACES(
  'http://www.google.com//services' AS ns1
) 
SELECT 
   t.c.value('ns1:Name[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)') AS name
FROM @x.nodes('//ns1:Info') as t(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can read xml data in SQL Server as below:

```
DECLARE @xml XML = 
'<DataTable>
    <Employee>
        <ID>100</ID>
        <Name>Rohan</Name>
        <Age>30</Age>
        <Gender>Male</Gender>
        <City>Delhi</City>
        <State>Delhi</State>
    </Employee>
</DataTable>'

SELECT
tbl.col.value('ID[1]', 'smallint') AS ID,
Tbl.Col.value('Name[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS Name,
Tbl.Col.value('Age[1]', 'smallint') AS Age,
Tbl.Col.value('Gender[1]', 'varchar(10)') AS Gender,
Tbl.Col.value('City[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS City,
Tbl.Col.value('State[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS State
 
FROM   @xml.nodes('/DataTable/Employee') tbl(col)
```

To read more on how to read xml data visit below link

[Read xml data as table in SQL Server](http://www.sqlrelease.com/read-xml-data-as-a-table-in-sql-server)

In case you want to read xml nodes dynamically with unknown number of elements, visit this link:

[Read xml nodes dynamically in SQL Server](http://www.sqlrelease.com/read-and-compare-xml-nodes-dynamically-with-unknown-elements)